# Decrypting PHP openssl_ecrypt with NodeJS crypto errors

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, openssl, cryptography

We have a legacy PHP system that encrypted some data via openssl_encrypt.  The PHP code is pretty straight forward.  (All values are randomly generated for this example, but are the same format and lengths as the real values and reproduce the same errors).

```
$in = '12345';
$method = 'AES-256-CBC';
$key = '5fjfwc7kp84z5yet358t';
$options = 0;
$iv = '8x69nt6qnptg3x4j';
openssl_encrypt($in, $method, $key, $options, $iv);
```

Decrypting via PHP is also pretty straight forward.

```
$in = 'yy03+cUpsq5uGWclBLtwIA==';
$method = 'AES-256-CBC';
$key = '5fjfwc7kp84z5yet358t';
$options = 0;
$iv = '8x69nt6qnptg3x4j';
openssl_decrypt($in, $method, $key, $options, $iv);
```

However, when trying to port it over to Node crypto I keep getting errors on key length, iv length, and numerous other errors as I try different approaches.

```
const input = Buffer.from('yy03+cUpsq5uGWclBLtwIA==');
const iv = Buffer.from('8x69nt6qnptg3x4j');
const key = Buffer.from('5fjfwc7kp84z5yet358t');

let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv, 0);
let clearText = decipher.update(input, 'base64', 'utf8');
clearText += decipher.final('utf8');
```

I've probably tried half a dozen or more examples in NodeJS and all produce errors and fail to decrypt entirely.

Current error is "Invalid key length" which remains the error even if I restrict it to 16 characters.

Comment: The key size for AES-256 is 23 bytes. PHP can tolerate smaller keys (I think it pads with zero bytes), but Node will throw an exception. Also you don't decode your ciphertext.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/35614#35614 (no it doesn't pad with zeroes, and its an openssl thing, not a PHP thing)

Comment: @symcbean I was referring to key padding, not plaintext padding. But you're right, it is an openssl thing, it has nothing to do with the language.

Comment: I have tried padding the key to 23 bytes and it still gives a key length error.  Also, what do you meany by "You don't decode your ciphertext"?

Comment: @Soabirw Sorry, that's a typo, I meant 32 bytes (256 bits = 32 bytes). And don't forget to base64-decode before decryption.

Comment: Okay, I added padding to 32 and now I'm getting the error:
error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt.  As for base64, isn't that what this is doing? decipher.update(input, 'base64', 'utf8');  Or Buffer.from('yy03+cUpsq5uGWclBLtwIA==', 'base64); ?

Comment: Yes, but in your `input` buffer you don't use the encoding parameter, at least not in your question. Either base64-decode in the buffer, or use a string and decode in `.update`,

Comment: Okay, I tried both approaches.  And they result in the same error.  But maybe padding on the key is still bad?  I'm just adding 0 until it hits 32.

Comment: A zero character is not a zero byte. You can create a zero byte buffer with `Buffer.alloc(n, 0x00)`, however it's best to change your PHP key. Also, please ping me if you want me to get your message. I happened to leave this page open in a tab, otherwise I wouldn't get your message.

Comment: @t.m.adam Thank you.  That did the trick.  Unfortunately, we can't change the PHP key as it's a vendor system and the data is already encrypted that way and has been for years.  But all this has produced the right results.  Do you want to do something so I can grant you the answer?

Comment: Glad it worked! It would be best to use a new key, as AES-256 supports really strong keys. You could use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` or `hash_pbkdf2` for password based keys. If you would like some advice, it's best to use a random IV for every encryption, and authenticate your data, or change the AES mode. Sorry, I don't have much spare time, but you could answer your question and accept your answer, if you want.

Comment: This content is not in any way sensitive.  It was a way for an API vendor to hide IDs so users couldn't just increment them in the query strings.  Pretty mild stuff all around.  Otherwise, I'd agree, we'd want much better encryption for more sensitive items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding and base64 processing was the solution.  Working code looks closer to this:

```
const keyStr = '5fjfwc7kp84z5yet358t';
const diff = Math.abs(keyStr.length - 32);
const padding = Buffer.alloc(diff, 0x00);
const input = Buffer.from('yy03+cUpsq5uGWclBLtwIA==', 'base64');
const iv = Buffer.from('8x69nt6qnptg3x4j');
let key = Buffer.from('5fjfwc7kp84z5yet358t');
key = Buffer.concat([key, padding]);

const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv, 0);
let clearText = decipher.update(input, 'base64', 'utf8');
clearText += decipher.final('utf8');
```